# How to add line to a file using Stream Writer in Powershell

Tags: powershell, filestream

I have 6GB sql file of insert statements where I would like to add a GO statement after each 150 lines. There are a total 9M lines in the file.

I found some code using Powershell script and most recommended the stream or .NET commands for performance with large files.

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("C:\src\customers1.sql")
$pathAndFilename = "c:\src\files\_customers_1.sql"
$streamout = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $pathAndFilename
$batchSize = 150
$counter = 0
try {
    for ( $line = $reader.ReadLine(); $line -ne $null; $line = $reader.ReadLine() ) 
    { 
        $streamout.writeline($line)
        $counter +=1
        if ($counter -eq $batchsize)
        {   
            $counter =0
            $_ # send the current line to output
            if ($_ -match ", NULL, NULL") 
            {
                #Add Lines after the selected pattern 
                $line="GO"
                $streamout.writeline($line)
            }
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
    $streamOut.close()
}
```

The above reads the source file and writes into the destination path in 3 minutes. However, it does not write the GO after each 150 lines of code. It seems to just copy the file over. Is there something I am missing in the code?

Comment: You're using the wrong variable for the current line.  `$_ -match ", NULL, NULL"` should be `$line -match ", NULL, NULL"`.

Comment: I don't see the reason why you have `$_` instead of `$line`. `$_` represents the pipeline object, but you don't seem to be using the pipeline for input here. Perhaps that's your issue

Comment: Thank you, @BACON. Your recommendation worked.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @MasonSchmidgall. I have updated my code.

Comment: Hello again! If @BACON 's comment fixed your code, he should post it as an answer and you should accept it to assist future visitors. If that did not solve your problem, please update your question. Thank you!

Comment: @MasonSchmidgall Instead of posting an answer I voted to close the question for being "caused by...a simple typographical error" since it was a minor naming issue specific to the code in the question and not a larger concept other readers would really benefit from.

Comment: Oh I forgot you could do that. I'll follow suit